# how to show total on graph on basis of sector and graph

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

what i am getting in tableset i want to show in graph

i want to show **total** on a graph i am new new to this but i able to show on table set let me know any approach for this
//ui.r

this is the png image of what i am getting

[image]

```
library(shiny)
        shinyUI(fluidPage(
          titlePanel("Store Name And There Date"),

      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(


          uiOutput("Box1"),
          uiOutput("Box2")
        ),
        mainPanel("Display results",
                  tableOutput("view"))
      )
    ))
```

//server.r

```
library(shiny)
biz = data.frame(
  Sector = c("New Piersons Pharmacy","New Piersons Pharmacy2","South Chemists","Sirota Pharmacy 2","SirotaPharmacy","Piersons Pharmacy","Channel Pharmacy","Orchid Pharmacy","ROYAL PHARMACY","Suwahasa pharmacy","Romed Pharmacy"), 
  Stock = c("2017-10-12","2017-10-13","2017-10-14","2017-10-18","2017-10-15","2017-10-16","2012-10-17", "2012-10-17", "2012-10-22", "2012-10-23","2012-10-21"),
  total = c("1233","12455","2342","3556","3567","34567","3423","5434","3456","2123","2213"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$Box1 = renderUI(selectInput("sector","select a storename",c(unique(biz$Sector),"pick one"),"pick one"))


  output$Box2 = renderUI(
    if (is.null(input$sector) || input$sector == "pick one"){return()
    }else selectInput("stock", 
                      "Select a Date", 
                      c(unique(biz$Stock[which(biz$Sector == input$sector)]),"pick one"),
                      "pick one")
  )


  subdata1 = reactive(biz[which(biz$Sector == input$sector),])
  subdata2 = reactive(subdata1()[which(subdata1()$Stock == input$stock),])

  output$view = renderTable({
    if(is.null(input$sector) || is.null(input$stock)){return()
    } else if (input$sector == "pick one" || input$stock == "pick one"){return()

    } else return(subdata2())
  })

})
```

Comment: i want to show total on any graph either hist or plot on the basis of selecttion

Comment: help me out with this